# How to get input from the user and push it to a list

Tags: c++, list, cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

#define print(x) std::cout << x
#define println(x) std::cout << x << std::endl

template<typename T>
T input(const char* string) {
    print(string);
    T temp{};
    std::cin >> temp;
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    std::list<char*> list_of_foods;
    char* food;
    while (1) {
        food = input<char*>("Enter a food name or (exit) to exit: ");
        if (food == "exit") { break; }
        else { list_of_foods.push_back(food); }
    }
    std::list<char*>::iterator food_iterator = list_of_foods.begin();
    println("Your order is:");
    while (food_iterator != list_of_foods.end()) {
        println(*food_iterator);
        food_iterator++;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to run this code but it exit when I try to type any food name with an "-1073741819" exit code, what did a do wrong exactly ?

Comment: @anastaciu is that better ?

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of C strings

Comment: Much better, yes.

Comment: you are not allocating any memory to hold the input, try using std::string instead of char*

Comment: @ThomasSablik Already tried it and it work, but std::string is heap allocated and i want something fast

Comment: Also `food == "exit"` is wrong way to compare C strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
T temp{};
```

Is initializing `temp` to `nullptr`, so you cannot have it read something there.

You should use `std::string` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // add this to use std::string
#include <list>

#define print(x) std::cout << x
#define println(x) std::cout << x << std::endl

template<typename T>
T input(const char* string) {
    print(string);
    T temp{};
    std::cin >> temp;
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    std::list<std::string> list_of_foods;
    std::string food;
    while (1) {
        food = input<std::string>("Enter a food name or (exit) to exit: ");
        if (food == "exit") { break; }
        else { list_of_foods.push_back(food); }
    }
    std::list<std::string>::iterator food_iterator = list_of_foods.begin();
    println("Your order is:");
    while (food_iterator != list_of_foods.end()) {
        println(*food_iterator);
        food_iterator++;
    }
}
```

If you want to use `char*` anyway, template specialization is useful to have it allocate buffer.
Also note that comparision of C-style string cannot be done via `==` and you should use `strcmp()` instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> // for using strcmp()
#include <list>

#define print(x) std::cout << x
#define println(x) std::cout << x << std::endl

template<typename T>
T input(const char* string) {
    print(string);
    T temp{};
    std::cin >> temp;
    return temp;
}

template<>
char* input(const char* string) {
    print(string);
    char* temp = new char[1024000]; // allocate enough size and pray not to be attacked
    std::cin >> temp;
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    std::list<char*> list_of_foods;
    char* food;
    while (1) {
        food = input<char*>("Enter a food name or (exit) to exit: ");
        if (strcmp(food, "exit") == 0) { break; }
        else { list_of_foods.push_back(food); }
    }
    std::list<char*>::iterator food_iterator = list_of_foods.begin();
    println("Your order is:");
    while (food_iterator != list_of_foods.end()) {
        println(*food_iterator);
        food_iterator++;
    }
}
```

Comment: "allocate enough size and pray not to be attacked" haha, Thx btw.
I'll accept your answer in a minute

Answer (score 0):

When you call `input` with a `char*` template parameter, the body of the function becomes:

```
// ...
char * temp{};
std::cin >> temp;
// ...
```

In this case, the `char*` is not pointing to valid memory, and trying to read a value into that will invoke undefined behavior.

You should just use `std::string` instead, since a `string` will be able to read in input without any need for allocating memory manually.